# CakePHP test behaviour with mapped method

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Whilst creating an `OwnableBehavior` I decided to use the `$mapMethods` property that is available. It is to map any method called `isOwnedByXXX()` to `isOwnedBy()` (The link for the documentation on this is [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#mapped-methods))

Here is my `OwnableBehavior` code:

```
class OwnableBehavior extends Model Behavior {

    public $mapMethods = array('/isOwnedBy(\w+)/' => 'isOwnedBy');

    public function isOwnedBy(Model $model, $type, $id, Model $userModel, $userId) {
         // Method is currently empty
    }
}
```

Here is the TestCase code:

```
class OwnableBehaviorTest extends CakeTestCase {

    public function testIsOwned() {
        $TestModel = new Avatar();
        $TestModel->Behaviors->attach('Ownable');
        $result = $TestModel->Behaviors->Ownable->isOwnedByUser(
            $TestModel, 1, new User(), 1);
        $this->assertTrue($result);
    }
}
```

When I run the test I get this error:

```
 Call to undefined method OwnableBehavior::isOwnedByUser()
```

If I change the method call to `isOwnedBy($TestModel, 'user', 1, new User(), 1);` this works, so it looks like for some reason the mapped methods aren't working during the unit test. I have tested the mapped methods in a controller and I get no errors.

I wondered if it was down to how I was loading the behaviour into the model. I couldn't find any documentation in the cookbook on how to properly test Behaviours like there is with Components, Helpers, etc... So I just used the same techniques that the Core Behaviour tests use (Found in `Cake/Test/Case/Model/Behavior/`).

I did think maybe it could have been down to the fact that I am overwriting the `ModelBehavior::setup()` method, but I tried adding `parent::setup($model, $settings)` at the start of the setup method and I still get the same error. I am not overwriting any of the other `ModelBehavior` methods.

I guess I could just use the `OwnableBehavior::isOwnedBy()` method, but I'd quite like to know if I could get the mapped methods to work during a unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I have found is replacing this line:

```
$result = $TestModel->Behaviors->Ownable->isOwnedByUser(...);
```

with:

```
$result = $TestModel->isOwnedByUser(...);
```

So it's just a case of using it more like you would in the application, calling the behaviour method directly from the model. I don't know if this ruins the idea of a unit test and makes it more into integration testing though.

Comment: The [mapped method logic](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.2/lib/Cake/Model/BehaviorCollection.php#L257) is implemented by the behavior _collection_ class that's why it doesn't work calling ->undefinedmethod on the behavior directly.